# LibreOffice Theme is Gray and Seems Broken

Tags: libreoffice

I just installed LibreOffice on v22 using Software Center (it's a snap). It looks unusually gray and ugly. How can I make it prettier?

[image]

Comment: 1. Are you using regular Ubuntu or some flavor of Ubuntu (e.g. Kubuntu)? 2. How did you install LibreOffice? Please edit the question to add these information

Comment: Where from and how did you install this? What command?

Comment: The Ubuntu Software store. So I'm assuming its a snap.

Comment: Btw are you using 22.04 or 22.10?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed LibreOffice via `apt`, install `libreoffice-gtk3` with:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3
```

In case you installed via `snap`, remove the `snap` version, and install the `apt` version with the following commands:

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
sudo apt install libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice
```

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: Not sure why (I didn't do it), but I'd honestly like to know how to fix the snap.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `gtk-common-themes` package using:

```
sudo snap install gtk-common-themes
```

See this similar issue on [Yaru's GitHub](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru): [Libreoffice snap theme broken](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/776)